# application id changed but firebase is still working

Tags: firebase

I tried to upload my application in playStore then an error came, which wanted me to change the package name from example to any other name. After that, I changed the package name and application id using an answer on StackOverflow.
After that when I installed my application, my authentication, firestore and database is still working with the new application id. People say that the application id is the only thing by which firebase knows the app. Of course a new apk was installed when I installed the app in my phone after renaming id.
So why this is happening that firebase is working with an app with different application id from the id that has been saved in the project in firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake - It was ok after one hour. Firebase took its time. My application got an error of mismatch of id in the studio.

So my concepts of application id are correct and working properly. I decided to put this question here so that anyone having this problem can know this solution.